# Counting number of numbers

Tags: counters, numbers

So I'm a Japanese learner just coming across how to count stuff like cars, or buildings, or bottles, or anything!

But I was just wondering, is there any counter to count numbers?

For example, you could say

> There are 12 numbers on the board.

So what can I use to count "numbers" & say the same sentence in Japanese?

Answer (score 4):

Use the generic counter 個.

> 数字が１２個あります。

If the count is limited, you can also use ひとつ, ふたつ, みっつ and so on.